# How do I trigger an on demand refresh/redraw of ol.Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, openlayers-3

I have a function called "LoadMap"

```
    rcisWebMapLoad.prototype.LoadMap = function (param1, param2) {
     //Get some vector objects and create layers
     var fieldVectorObjs = rcisWebMapVectorObjs.GetFieldVectorObjects(param1, param2);
        var objectVectorLines = rcisWebMapVectorObjs.GetLinesVectorObjects(param1, param2, 1);

       //Create Map object and add layers then insert into map div
        control.map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            renderer: 'canvas',
            layers: layers,
            view: new ol.View({
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 8
            })
        });

           //******* MapServer imagery ***************
            var aerial = new ol.layer.Tile({
                name: 'Imagery',
                source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                    url: mapServerPath.ResponseString,
                    params: { 'LAYERS': 'aerial', 'FORMAT': 'image/png', 'TILED': true },
                    serverType: 'mapserver'

                })

            });
            control.map.addLayer(aerial);


    }
```

This loads the map great!!

I have my imagery and vector objects on the map...however the problem comes when I want to switch to a different map ie.(Different imagery and vector objects)...

**UPDATE:**
originally I thought the map was not getting updated but in reality another map get's generated and added right under the original map...How do I reuse or replace the map object that is already there to display another map?

Because I'm using AngularJS and passing the maps parameters through a service I can not just call the page again and get the parameters from the query string as someone suggested to me before.

This seems like something that would be a main function for an online map.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: did you try `map.getView().changed()`??? This should fire the change event to your map view. http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html#changed. Or maybe `map.changed()`

Comment: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html#render is going to redraw the map. There is also http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html#renderSync which is synchronous.

Comment: Yes, I have tried all this and nothing happens???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was not able to force an on-demand refresh of the map object for OpenLayers 3.

So what I ended up doing was to destroy the map object and create a new one each time.

so for the example above it would look like this...

**For angularJS users you also need to make sure that you create an empty map in your .factory load function (so there is something to destroy initially)...if you're not using angular you would just need to create the map on page load**.

```
 function rcisWebMapLoad() {          

        this.map = new ol.Map({});

    }



 rcisWebMapLoad.prototype.LoadMap = function (param1, param2) {
 //Get some vector objects and create layers
 var fieldVectorObjs = rcisWebMapVectorObjs.GetFieldVectorObjects(param1, param2);
    var objectVectorLines = rcisWebMapVectorObjs.GetLinesVectorObjects(param1, param2, 1);

        var layers = [];
```

**Destroy map object before creating a new one**

```
     control.map.setTarget(null);
     control.map = null;

   //Create Map object and add layers then insert into map div
    control.map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        renderer: 'canvas',
        layers: layers,
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 8
        })
    });

       //******* MapServer imagery ***************
        var aerial = new ol.layer.Tile({
            name: 'Imagery',
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: mapServerPath.ResponseString,
                params: { 'LAYERS': 'aerial', 'FORMAT': 'image/png', 'TILED': true },
                serverType: 'mapserver'

            })

        });
        control.map.addLayer(aerial);


}
```